# page jump from div to an anchor

Tags: html, anchor, page-jump

I was trying to make a div jump from `<a href="#FAQ">FAQ</a>` to a `div` id and could success easily, but since I have a fixed link to jump to, I can't seem to find a way how to do that.

Meaning, I want a **div** or **a href** link to jump to a url in the same page say `<a href="http://www.mydomain.ask.html">Ask</a>`

I know for sure that jumping from an anchor such as `<a href="#jump">jump</a>` to a div such as `<div id="jump">jump to point</div>` works fine. However, how about the opposite way? does it work? I mean jumping from div id to an anchor works?

Comment: if I didn't try it, would why I ask then? :)

Comment: I would recommend creating simple html file to test what you want to do.

Comment: why don't you (@Digitalsite) try it then ??

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As long as your anchor has an ID you can link to a location in your view by clicking the `div` you will just need some javascript.

Setting the `window.location.hash` value will put the focus of the view on the selected ID.

**Sample**

```
<a href="#test1" id="back">Test</a>

<div id="test1" onclick="window.location.hash='back'; ">
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GP77J/2/)

Comment: ok, great solution. This is what I did,too. However, what I want to do is jumping from the `div id="test1"` to `a href="#test1"`, not the normal way we know...

Comment: just found out in your example that I have to click **test** to jump to the **target div** and then click the **target div** to go back to **test** anchor, which is good. however, I want only a jump from **target div** to **test** "one way"

Comment: You do not _have_ to use the exact example I provided.

Comment: In regards to not using the **ID** to set the focus you still need to find the element in the DOM to set the focus.  Using an element is the fastest way to search the DOM other searches (such as finding anchor tags with a specific href value) would impact performance.

Comment: ok, great to know. Thanks a lot. I will keep digging finding the best possible way without affecting the performance. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think then you have to add `<a href="yourid">page place</a>` inside your first div and have to give id to your  anchor tag `<a href="yourplace" id="idname"></a>`

Comment: this solution is going somewhere around the right track... not sure if I can understand it well. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4):

if you have link to go another with variable
you can use with id # sign

```
<a href="product.php?action=edit#lastdiv>Go to Product Last Div</a>

<div id="lastdiv">There are last product Exist</div>
```