# Div anchor tag in a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Apologies if this question is flooded in the internet but nothing works in my favor.

I thought all you need to do is add the `# + div id` at the end of a url which matches the div you are going to.

I want when I got to a particular url, the view port goes to that div. For example:

```
www.foo.com/bar#5
```

**Takes me to:**

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5">
 <!-- You have found me! -->
</div>
```

I have not much experience with this part of html and wonder if [JavaScript is involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813719/page-jump-from-div-to-an-anchor)?

Back in the days I used to use Dreamweaver and added an anchor tag was just a click of a button so never knew the actual work behind it.

My frontend is React; using Rails 5.

My react layout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you are correct but have in mind that if your react application doesn't use server side rendering, all you deliver to your users is a blank page in which react later renders the dom. The problem with this is, that when the browser loads the page initially and searches for an element with the id the document might be empty.

Comment: The old way you could/can use `name="5"` but that still not working. My page is not blank. I have divs with material-like cards.

Comment: do you have server side rendering?

Comment: Found the problem: an ID may not start with a digit